# Cannot get HTML element on top of another element

Tags: html, css, position, z-index

Edited to explain difference between linked question:

The problem I have is different as:
1. The elements which I want to overlay are unrelated
2. These are svg elements

Can someone suggest a working solution for these circumstances please?

---

I basically want to put all the text elements on top of path elements. It seems I'm following the standard rules (elements positioned with z-index set) for this yet it doesn't work. Why is that?

```css
text {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2
}
path {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<svg width="1191" height="751"><g id="holdDonut" transform="translate(595.5,375.5)">
  <g class="arc">
    <path d="M2.238042025441788e-14,-365.5A365.5,365.5,0,0,1,13.18655527399621,-365.2620494384899L6.593277636998105,-182.63102471924495A182.75,182.75,0,0,0,1.119021012720894e-14,-182.75Z" style="fill: rgb(152, 171, 197);"></path>
    <text transform="translate(4.9457632502712405,-274.0803806383672)" dy=".35em">28</text></g>
  <g class="arc">
    <path d="M13.18655527399621,-365.2620494384899A365.5,365.5,0,1,1,-6.714126076325364e-14,-365.5L-3.357063038162682e-14,-182.75A182.75,182.75,0,1,0,6.593277636998105,-182.63102471924495Z" style="fill: rgb(138, 137, 166);">
  </path>
  <text transform="translate(-4.9457632502711455,274.0803806383672)" dy=".35em">3 086</text>
  </g>
  </g>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLGGpz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [z-index in css doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377029/z-index-in-css-doesnt-work)

Comment: That's not how SVG paths & elements are positioned. That's what the `viewbox` co-ordinate system is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `text` element above to the `path` element